# Redirect to Shipping tab is not working from Payment tab in checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I have an Magento 2.4.3-p1 version, when we go through the Shipping tab to Payment page, we are unable to go back to shipping tab in checkout. This is the error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: billingAddress(...).needCancelBillingAddressChanges is not a function
    at Object.navigateTo (progress-bar.min.js:2:186)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (bundle-common.min.js:1:170548)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (bundle-common.min.js:1:47305)
    at g.handle (bundle-common.min.js:1:43898)
```

Anyone has solution for this.